# Wildcards in sudoers rule

Tags: sudo

These lines from the command line explain my use case:

> Wildcards in command line arguments should be used with care.  Because command line arguments are matched as a single, concatenated string, a wildcard such
>        as ‘?’ or ‘*’ can match multiple words.  For example, while a sudoers entry like:
>
> ```
>      %operator ALL = /bin/cat /var/log/messages*
>
>  will allow command like:
>
>      $ sudo cat /var/log/messages.1
>
>  It will also allow:
>
>      $ sudo cat /var/log/messages /etc/shadow
> ```
>
> which is probably not what was intended.

How to allow the operator to see all files which start with `/var/log/messages`?

Spaces do not appear in the filenames.

I would like the `*` to  act like the PCRE `\S*`

## Update

Since `sudo` does not support regular expressions, I created a new question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/65887/sudo-alternative-which-supports-pcre

Above example is from `man sudoers`. Part "Wildcards in command line arguments should be used with care."

Comment: have you considered writing a wrapper script (say, /usr/local/bin/catmsg) which checks its arguments and only allows those matching `/var/log/messages*` (or, better yet, where readlink proves they match that) ?   then allow sudo access to that script instead of to cat with a wildcard arg?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro what do you mean with "group"?

Comment: Original message should have been why not a specific group? I usually give var log messages the adm group and modify logrotate to give the necessary files the adm Unix group. So then you just need  to add an operator to the adm group

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the file `/var/log/messages` is just an example. This example is from from the man-page. I could have written "/foo/bar", too. This question is about the missing feature which is examplained in the man page.

Answer (score 2):

The sudoers syntax doesn't provide a way out, and I might suggest writing a wrapper script (say, ignore everything but the first argument, and canonicalise it using `realpath`) and friends), but it wouldn't be useful anyway:

```
sudo cat /var/log/messages/../../../etc/shadow
```

Without knowing your actual usecase, I can only comment on the example from the manpage, and for that I would say the actual solution is to not use sudo at all, but use ACLs. Use ACLs to grant a user access for everything in the directory, and the filesystem will take care of limiting their access.

Comment: When I tried `cat /var/log/messages/../syslog` I got `cat: /var/log/messages/../syslog: Not a directory` so I think you're probably safe there.

Answer (score 2):

For your case I think the closest you can get is something like:

```sudoers
%operator ALL = /bin/cat /var/log/messages*, !/bin/cat /var/log/messages*\ *
```

which first allows `/bin/cat` only if it has any "argument string" beginning with `/var/log/messages`, and then forbids that same "argument string" if it has a space at any point.

This practically forbids multiple arguments to `cat`, but being on a "whole string" basis it does not allow `sudo cat /var/log/messages /var/log/messages.1` as much as it does not allow `sudo cat /var/log/messages /etc/shadow`. Also, it does not allow a legal filename having a space, e.g. a hypothetical `/var/log/messages-with-' '-space` file.

Comment: This works, but looks fragile. Since `sudo` is about security, I would like to avoid this solutions, since it is likely that someone will do it wrong.

Comment: @guettli This is what is doable with `sudo` own rule system. Other approaches might be through LinuxSecurityModules, like e.g. AppArmor which supports an enhanced glob syntax applied on a file basis, or SELinux which does support regexs for its fcontext labels. Naturally all these bring along many other complexities, but if any one of these is already in operation on your system it becomes quick and easy to add file-oriented rules. Else, if you are determined with regexs on `sudo`, you could also develop your own plugin for that

Comment: I am astonished that no alternative to sudo exists which supports regexs. It is a common question. I asked here and got up-votes, but up to now no answer:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/65887/sudo-alternative-which-supports-pcre

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be a custom script, `/usr/local/bin/cat-messages`, to perform the validation outside `sudoers`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
args=()
prefix='/var/log/messages'

for arg in "$@"
do
    # Canonicalise
    real=$(readlink -f "$arg")

    # Check it is a real file matching the prefix
    if [[ "$real" =~ ^"$prefix" ]] && [[ -f "$real" ]]
    then
        args+=("$arg")
    else
        echo "WARNING: skipping $arg" >&2
    fi
done

cat "${args[@]}"
```

You could add this to `sudoers` with a line something like this

```
%operator ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/cat-messages
```

And (assuming `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`) call it like this

```
sudo cat-messages /var/log/messages.1 /var/log/messages
```

Actually, since it's a shell script there's little stopping you getting it to call itself with `sudo`, making life simpler for users. (There's no security issue here because `sudo` will still only consider `/usr/local/bin/cat-messages`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
[[ $(id -u) != 0 ]] && exec sudo "$0" "$@"

args=()
prefix='/var/log/messages'
... as before ...
```

You'd call this variant simply like this

```
cat-messages /var/log/messages.1 /var/log/messages
```

or

```
cat-messages /var/log/messages*
```